# How can I remove consecutive duplicates using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, duplicates

I need to remove consecutive duplicates from a string with a recursion method (for example, turning "aabbcddeghhi" into "abcdefghi.") I have this so far.

If I have the `removeDuplicates()` line that's commented, I get a strange output with numbers and this exception:

> ```
> a195b197199d201203205207h209Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13
> ```

If I comment out that line, it just prints:

```
a
```

Here is my code:

```
package recursion;

public class recursion {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        removeDuplicates("aabbcddefghhi", 0, 1);
    }

    public static void removeDuplicates(String a, int b, int c){
        if (a.length() <= 1){
            System.out.print(a.charAt(b));
        }
        else if (a.charAt(b) == a.charAt(c)){
            System.out.print(a.charAt(c));
            b++;
            c++;
            //removeDuplicates(a,b,c);
        }
        else if (a.charAt(b) != a.charAt(c)){
            System.out.print(a.charAt(b) + a.charAt(c));
            b++;
            c++;
            removeDuplicates(a,b,c);
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("");
            b++;
            c++;
            removeDuplicates(a,b,c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the **specific** problem you're having? Please [edit] your question with this information. Recommended reading: [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with this code:

1. You don't have a good way to terminate the recursion. You aren't actually reducing the size of the string, so your initial ending condition won't work.
2. You don't have a case to print the last character of the string based on the logic you're using here.
3. Your final if condition will never occur
4. You don't want to add two characters together, ever. You also don't want to print both characters in that case.
5. You don't want to print a character if the two characters match, because you don't know how many more characters there are going to be.
6. You don't need to have a `c` value, it's always equal to `b+1`, just use one number.

Here's the resulting code with all these changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  removeDuplicates("a");
  System.out.println();
  removeDuplicates("aabbcdddefghhii");
  System.out.println();
  removeDuplicates("aabbcdefa");
}

public static void removeDuplicates(String a) {
   removeDuplicatesHelper(a, 0);
}

public static void removeDuplicatesHelper(String a, int b) {
  if (b == a.length() - 1) {
    System.out.print(a.charAt(b));
  } else if (a.charAt(b) == a.charAt(b+1)) {
    b++;
    removeDuplicatesHelper(a, b);
  } else {
    System.out.print(a.charAt(b));
    b++;
    removeDuplicatesHelper(a, b);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
a
abcdefghi
abcdefa
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work if I changed to the string to something like "aabbcdefa" so that it would output "abcdefa"? At some point, the "f" gets removed. I assume that happens in the first "else if" because of "a.length()-1", but a != f, so it shouldn't get removed.
(It's 12:17am so I could be sleep-deprived and misreading it, but I don't fully understand it.)

Comment: How would I fix it if I took out the int parameter? I declared b as a static variable outside of the methods and I set it as a.length(). I get a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception no matter if I leave it at that, add or subtract 1. I've played around with the numbers in the removeDuplicates method, too. I'm sure it's something obvious I'm missing. Even just pointing me in the right direction would help.

Comment: I've tried it with b starting at 0, as well. That didn't print out the desired result, either.

Comment: I was just told to change it to only have a string parameter in the removeDuplicates method. What changes would have to be made? Or is there a way to change it a different way?

Comment: (Sorry to keep bothering you.) We haven't learned about tail-recursion in my class yet, so I don't know if I should use that. It's giving me an error anyway.

Comment: You're right, I messed around with my code between answers so it wasn't like that. I'm not sure I'm allowed to do something like that, though. Is there no other way to solve it recursively aside from an int parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String duplicates(String word, char curr) {

    if (word.length() == 0) return "";

    char next = word.charAt(0);

    if (word.length() == 1) {
       return curr == next ? "" : word;
    }

    if (curr != next) {
         return next + duplicates(word.substring(1), next);
    }
    else {
        return duplicates(word.substring(1), curr);
    }
 }
```

Call as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(duplicates("aabbbbbb976fkkkkc", '\0'));
}
```